# Setting the stack pointer in AVR microcontrollers with C code

Tags: c, stack

It is known that in AVR microcontrollers the stack pointer decreases for each element added to the stack. I want to reserve memory for a new task stack, and I use

```
unsigned char *pS = (unsigned char*)malloc(64*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

This I think returns a pointer to *the beginning* of an area in SRAM followed by 64 bytes, therefore for setting the stack pointer at the new stack I use

```
SP = (unsigned int)pS + 64
```

Is this correct?

Comment: [don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: and `sizeof(unsigned char)` is completely redundant, it's defined to be `1`.

Comment: apart from that, looks correct, but there's no way to set a stack pointer in C .. C doesn't know what a *stack pointer* **is**. You'll have to write (maybe embed) some assembler code. While at it, it's probably unnecessary to use `malloc()`, just use a linker script and reserve some space for a second stack.

Comment: I definitely would not use malloc and write own memory manager. Remember that you work with tiny amount of RAM

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... SP = *(the adress of the stack pointer) it is defined some where

Comment: But I am more interested here if it is correct to add the the address returned by malloc the number of bytes allocated to be a valid stack pointer ...

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc it is silly. This advice comes from the ancient era when compilers were not issuing warnings about implicit declarations. Nowadays if someone is ignoring this warning - will ignore other as well :). The rest is only style of coding which is 100% opinion based.

Comment: @PeterJ I agree that this particular "pet peeve" of the SO community is mostly nonsense. But there are several answers posted in that thread, including [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538350/584518) which states that apart from adding clutter, the cast isn't even an issue since the year 1999. Overall it is better to keep the whole malloc debate inside that thread.

Comment: Yes but some users put this link and remark in almost every topic with the malloc involved. It become some kind of religion.

Comment: @PeterJ Indeed. Perhaps we should start flagging these as "not constructive" or alternatively raise some meta discussion.

Comment: Nothing will stop the myth to be thoughtlessly  repeated all over again.

Comment: One does not simply change the SP manually through code, it just doesn't make sense. Configure the AVR to use a specific amount of stack, it will reserve the right amount of bytes. And what is a "task stack"? How will this be used in your program?

Comment: @PeterJ it's not silly, but for different reasons. Pointer casts in C (not C++) are a *code smell*. Unfortunately, the accepted answer in the linked question gives a very outdated reason instead.

Comment: @Groo I wanted to have some space in RAM, to be considered as a stack. That is, after I make the Stack Pointer to point at the end of that memory location, I expect "push" and "pop" to operate on that memory ...

Comment: @Lundin I [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713482/2371524) as well because I felt the need to explain a not outdated reason I consider to be very strong.

Comment: @Felix Palmen your answer is unfortunately about something else.

Comment: @PeterJ no it isn't. But to understand this requires you to understand the abstractions the C standard makes from real machines. Btw, you should comment over there...

Comment: @Felix Palmen so lets leave it . I am too dumb to understand this level of abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not correct.

- Using malloc on an AVR for any purpose is definitely incorrect, because it doesn't make any sense. [See this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581). In addition, how does it even make sense to have the stack residing on the heap?
- If you need RTOS-like behavior, it means you already picked the wrong MCU for the task. 8-bitters are just far too limited. At a minimum, use a Cortex-M0 for such programs.

That being said, if you want to make your own simple task-switching OS just for the sake of learning, then you would reserve stack space at compile/link-time. This is done through the linker files of your cross-compiler environment. Check how and where the ordinary stack was allocated and then create a custom memory segment of similar size. You'll note that there is not a whole lot of RAM to play with at all.

It is correct that your stack pointer would be at an offset of the stack size. But if you are truly writing an OS, then you wouldn't be allocating the SP as some sort of C pointer, but rather you would let the CPU use the actual SP register.

Also note that setting the stack pointer is one of those things that simply can't be done in C. You must do so through assembler.

Comment: @tilz0R Just read the linked post. Atmel AVR is a 8 bit MCU with very little RAM memory. Anyone using malloc on such a system is confused, simple as that.

Comment: @tilz0R The question just asks "is this correct?" and I find nothing in the question that _is_ correct.

Comment: @tilz0R If the OP was merely asking if their syntax was correct, then any compiler ought could tell them.

Comment: in another OP question he was already told that the avr is not the very best choice. But he has decided to go ahead with it

Comment: Good answer as always, but out of interest, do you even have the need to use memory pools ("object pools") when programming embedded microcontrollers without RTOS?

Comment: @Groo Sometimes you do, when designing for OO by using opaque pointers. Since malloc isn't an option and that technique relies on the "class" doing the object allocation internally, each such class ends up with its own memory pool. Typically just 10 objects or so, at most.